# Audio Jack Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: audio-jack

I'm a Linux noob and was wondering if any one could help me. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on an Acer r11 and it won't recognize the audio jack.

However sound does work when I plug in my usb headphones. Also my internal speakers work fine. I've tried pretty much everything and came to this as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You should try playing with `alsamixer` *levels and switches*.

Maybe headphones channel is disabled or have zero default volume, like in the next image *(my laptop without headset plugged in)*.

[image: Alsamixer disabled and unplugged example]

With your headset/headphones plugged in, open `alsamixer` and look for heaphones/headset entry, then check if it is enabled (M to switch ON/OFF) and also it has 100% (or any non-zero value) volume.

[image: Alsamixer enabled and plugged example]

You can save your settings with `sudo alsactl store` which saves current config to */etc/asound.state*, which gets loaded every startup.

Hope it helps.

*Note: I would also check if speaker is auto disabled when plug-in the headphones to see if the plug-in event is detected/managed at all.*